# Why does it display the address like this in web api (asp.net core 6)?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I get this problem when I run the port inside the docker container.

I have used the attribute like this :

```
[HttpGet("{id:length(24)}", Name = "GetProduct")]
```

[Api List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJztI.png)

But when I use the internal port of the project (lunchSettings), it is displayed correctly

I want to call this address:

http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Catalog/602d2149e773f2a3990b47f5

But when I  Containerize my project, the address changes like this :

http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Catalog/602d2149e773f2a3990b47f5:length(24)

"length(24)"
I don't want it to be added to the end

```
[HttpGet("{id:length(24)}", Name = "GetProduct")] 
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Product), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetProductById(string id)
    {
        var product = await _productRepository.GetProduct(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Product with id: {id}, not found.");
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(product);
    }
```

docker compose:
[docker compose code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl5YC.png)

Comment: your question is not clear. what is your issue, accessing API from container or format of address ?

Comment: I want to call this address: 

http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Catalog/602d2149e773f2a3990b47f5

But when I  Containerize my project, the address changes like this :

http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Catalog/602d2149e773f2a3990b47f5:length(24)


"length(24)" 
I don't want it to be added to the end

Comment: Please add your dockerfile and your code, otherwise, we can't help you. Btw: this is very unlikely to have anything at all to do with the containerization of your app.

Comment: I put the file and the code

Comment: I already had an image with the same name (catalog.api) in docker that was causing this problem, I changed the name and now the problem is fixed, thanks everyone